# Doctrine error when using SUM(a.id=1) as `ìdentifier`: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '='

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

I am trying to execute a query in doctrine that contains something like this

```
SUM(a.id = 1) as `1`
```

for some reasons it always gives me the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 15: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '='
```

This is the code i am using

```
 $result = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:PlayerAction')
            ->createQueryBuilder('pa')
            ->select(array(
                'SUM(a.id=1) as `1`,
                SUM(a.id=2) as `2`,
                SUM(a.id=3) as `3`,
                p.playerName,
                pa.timestamp'
            ))
            ->innerJoin('pa.action', 'a')
            ->innerJoin('pa.player', 'p')
            ->where('pa.timestamp > ?1')
            ->groupBy('p')
            ->setParameter(1, time() - $time)
            ->orderBy('p.playerName', 'ASC');
```

Comment: I guess you dont need back-ticks in dql as `1` to sum_1 or you might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513384/cumulative-dql-with-doctrine

Comment: But the error is indication its crashing on the a.id=1, the = sign. I think it is searching for the end of the sum function, the closing bracket )

Comment: What would you expect from `SUM(a.id=1)`? What this statement must do?

Comment: It sums up the id fields (could be count as well, yes), i tried it in mysql and it gives me the correct result. Just fails on the = in doctrine

Comment: Hmm it keeps throwing this error and i cant find a solution in the documentation

Comment: Instead of : SUM(a.id=1) as `1` Maybe should you try to do something like (SUM(a.id) Where a.id = 1) as '1'

Comment: I need 3 fields, i don't think that will work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the error message, it appears Doctrine does some parsing of its own on your MySQL expressions. As already suggested by nietonfir, this parser may not be fully compliant to MySQL's. You could try some syntactic variations, for example:

```
SUM(CASE a.id WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `1`,
SUM(CASE a.id WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `2`,
SUM(CASE a.id WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `3`
```

or:

```
SUM(IF(a.id=1, 1, 0)) as `1`,
SUM(IF(a.id=2, 1, 0)) as `2`,
SUM(IF(a.id=3, 1, 0)) as `3`
```

If that fails, refactor the query; something along this line (just thinking out loud here; I'll leave the QueryBuilder equivalent up to you):

```
SELECT
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PlayerAction AS pa WHERE pa.player = p.id AND pa.timestamp > ?1 AND pa.action = 1) AS `1`,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PlayerAction AS pa WHERE pa.player = p.id AND pa.timestamp > ?1 AND pa.action = 2) AS `2`,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PlayerAction AS pa WHERE pa.player = p.id AND pa.timestamp > ?1 AND pa.action = 3) AS `3`,
   p.playerName
FROM Player p
ORDER BY p.playerName ASC
```

This may negatively affect query performance.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine doesn't seem to support that kind of syntax. You can either rewrite your query (subqueries or some joins would come to mind) or resort to a native MySQL-Query.

Comment: I tried writing native queries, however i don't quite get how those work within doctrine

Comment: Try the question and solution provided for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120701/doctrine-2-native-query